# The '__proto__' property is deprecated. (W103) jshint

Tags: javascript, jshint

Всем привет. В общем и целом: `The '__proto__' property is deprecated. (W103)` - вот такую PROBLEMS'у выдает мне jshint в VSCode редакторе, когда я пытаюсь сделать один объект прототипом другого объекта следующим способом:

```
let cat = {
hp: 580,
food = 1000
}

let dog = {
hp: 100
}

dog.__proto__ = cat;
```

Почитал про `prototype` и `__proto__`. Одно для функций, другое для объектов. Xочется избавиться от проблемсы этой, как можно это сделать?

Comment: Может, уже на классы перейти?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасиб

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вам и правда будет проще использовать синтаксический сахар классов. Но если вам не нужна вся механика классов, а нужно простое наследование, есть другие варианты.

1. Чтобы не получать подобных сообщений, можно использовать [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). Но как вы прочитаете в статье по ссылке, изменение прототипа объекта после создания неэффективно.
2. Можно использовать [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) с одним аргументом, создав пустой объект `dog` и потом изменить нужные свойства. Но если в подчинённом объекте вы хотите создавать свойства, которых нет в объекте-прототипе, это опять-таки не советуется разработчиками движков (по крайней мере V8) — добавление или удаление полей объекта после создания замедляет работу движка с этим объектом.
3. Наиболее универсальный и немного более сложный путь — использовать [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) со вторым аргументом, с объектом дескрипторов, в котором можно задать не только изменённые, но и новые свойства.